# Preventing logging of multiple analytics transactions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a Single Page Application with a payment page. My payment uses an iFrame for the payment form. So, when a payment happens and a webhook is called on the server, the server broadcasts this "payment" event to ALL of the open tabs owned by that specific user, using a WebSocket. This means that potentially 2. 4 or 9 browsers will potentially get the event.

If I base the firing of the "purchase" analytics event, I will *potentially* log multiple "purchase" events, one for each open tab getting the event via Websockets.

Please note that they could be all different sessions, on different devices, using different browsers.

I *could* log things from the server, even if it's just for the payment. But... does that make sense?

Comment: Why can't you just catch the actual submit for analytics?

Comment: Because there is no"submit", since it happens in an IFrame...

Comment: Is that an iframe  you control code on? If so can update parent page on submit and trigger ga event there

Comment: It's a payment form from the credit card provider -- of course I have zero control on what's in the iframe...